# <asp:Checkbox>'s jQuery click() event not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I have an ASP.NET-rendered CheckBox. When clicked, I want jQuery to capture the event, but for some reason it is not working.

This is what I'm doing so far:

**ASP.NET**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                 id="testcb" name="testcb" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#testcb").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) alert("checked");
});
```

Here is the source code from the browser:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <span name="testcb">
   <input id="testcb" type="checkbox" 
          name="ctl00$ctl00$bodyContent$phMainContent$testcb">
  </span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? That code appears to work perfectly for me. See the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/9za2p/0/

Comment: Please take a look at the HTML which your code is generating, and update your answer with that included.

Comment: I have updated http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/9za2p/1/ to reflect that code - and my result is the same. Please confirm whether the jsfiddle I'm linking works for you as-intended? Also, please confirm that you are putting the jQuery portion inside of a `$(document).on('load' ...)` or something similar.

Comment: I posted an answer which I think will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is likely that your jQuery script is being fired before the element in question is rendered.

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('ready', function () {
      $("#testcb").on('click', function () {
          var $cb = $(this);
          if ($cb.is(':checked')) {
              alert("checked");
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Without the `$(document).on('ready' ...` portion, you are not guaranteed that the document is fully rendered in the browser prior to `.click()` being bound. In addition, `.on()` should work even on elements that do not exist prior to it being called (similar to the old `.live()` function in previous versions of jQuery).

Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/9za2p/2/) as an example.

Comment: worked perfectly! How did you figure this out?  I've spent way too many hours trying to get this to work.  Thanks! :)

Comment: lol - I've done the exact same thing -many- times. :) Hours later, I suddenly remember, and /facepalm. :) Glad it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testcb").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
      alert("checked");
    } else {
      alert("unchecked");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand the if/else...great addition.  But for some reason, nothing is happening when clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Since an ASP check box actually resolves to a span and an input you probably want to check the first child of the check box:

```
$("#testcb").click(function () {
        if ($(this).children(':first').is(':checked')) alert("checked");
 });
```

EDIT:

I usually set an onclick in the declaration of the check box so I am not sure if this will work but try this:

```
$("#testcb").children(':first').click(function () {
        alert('fire!');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) alert("checked");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and I see what you are saying, and I made the changes, but it still does nothing when I click the checkbox on or off.